# RegExp to format a json string with curly braces

Tags: json, string-formatting

I have a json object as following, firstly base on the values of properties user_ids and acct_id to search through users and accounts, than format the desc into complete sentence, e.g. "Mary creates Saving Account" or "Peter transfers to John Debit Account"
I finished the searching part, and working on the string formatting.
Because I am not very familiar with ES, want to make sure I am on the right path. Should I use regexp to do this? Or ES has some functions I can use?

```
{  
   "transactions":[  
      {  
         "created_at":"2017-06-24T16:30:40+10:00",
         "desc":"{ user:4321 } creates { acct:1357 }",
         "act":"create",
         "acct_id":1357,
         "user_ids":[  
            4321
         ]
      },
      {  
         "created_at":"2017-06-24T16:30:40+10:00",
         "desc":"{ user:2456 } transfers to { user:7890 }{ acct:0987 }",
         "act":"transfer",
         "acct_id":9870,
         "user_ids":[  
            2456,
            7890
         ]
      }
   ],
   "users":[  
      {  
         "id":4321,
         "name":"Mary"
      },
      {  
         "id":2456,
         "name":"Peter"
      },
      {  
         "id":7890,
         "name":"John"
      }
   ],
   "accounts":[  
      {  
         "id":1357,
         "usder_id":4321,
         "type":"Saving Account"
      },
      {  
         "id":9870,
         "usder_id":7890,
         "type":"Debit Account"
      },
      {  
         "id":4234,
         "usder_id":7890,
         "type":"Credit Account"
      }
   ]
}
```